# What is the power output of the FireWire 800 port in the Late 2012 Mac Mini?

Tags: mac-mini, firewire

The Mac Mini (Late 2012) has a FireWire 800 port on the back.

[image: Mac Mini]

How much power can this FireWire port output? I was only able to find the data speed (800 Mbit/s) on Apple's tech specs page for this Mac mini, but wasn't able to find any information elsewhere.

For reference, the (now discontinued) 13 port Thunderbolt 3 docking station from OWC contained a FireWire 800 port that could output [7 watts of energy](https://www.lifewire.com/mac-usb-c-to-old-peripherals-4122273).

Comment: Just checked on a MacBook Pro, but in System Preferences, Available Current was shown for USB ports in mA (since there were no FireWire ports to check). As a quick reference, 1000 mA = 1 watt. Does System Preferences show you anything for that port?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Mac mini to check that on, so I was curious. Why do you say that 1000 mA = 1W though? Wouldn't that mean voltage is 1 V? I've read that FireWire carries from 8 to 30 volts

Comment: Got that info from a quick unit conversion check. Another factor may be how much that machine is getting in total from the power supply.

Comment: I believe 1000 mA should be 1 watt/volt, which means that you need to multiply the 1 by the voltage output to the port. Just an fyi, but you may already know that